# connect EACCES 0.0.0.0:443 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, axios

I am trying to hit an API that is deployed on AWS from my node js code using axios.

Here is my code:

```
var url = //url goes here
var jsonObject = //request body in json format
var options = //headers
await axios.post(url, jsonObejct, options);
```

Before today same code was working fine. But now it throw some error as given below :

> {"message":"connect EACCES 0.0.0.0:443","stack":"Error: connect EACCES 99.86.42.42:443\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1134:16)","config":{"url":"API url","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","Authorization":"token","User-Agent":"axios/0.19.2","Content-Length":393},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1},"code":"EACCES"}

Summary error message :

> connect EACCES 0.0.0.0:443","stack":"Error: connect EACCES 99.86.42.42:443\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1134:16)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Where is your code running from an EC2 in a VPC?

Comment: @DavidWebster API that I hit, deployed on AWS VPC. And it's a desktop app from where i hit this request.

Comment: What region is your AWS VPC in and are you sure you are using the correct one?

Comment: AWS Region is us-east-2,Yes

Comment: Assuming your VPC configuration is correct and has been working in the past, the only explanation for the above error is a poor internet connection. But then, my assumption is VPC was working fine